# Include parenthesis from regex capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm almost there but I don't know how to include the parenthesis from the string.

This is my code:

```js
var string = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (l OR p )" 

var result = string.replace(/.*\(([a-z].+)$/ig, "$1")

console.log(result)
```

This is the output:

l OR p )

And what I want is this:

(l OR p )

Comment: Move the parenthesis inside the capture group.

Comment: Use `/.*(\([a-z].+)$/i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the parentheses to be inside the capture group.

```js
var string = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (l OR p )" 

var result = string.replace(/.*(\([a-z].+\))$/ig, "$1")

console.log(result)
```

Here they are side-by-side so you can easily see the difference:

```
\(([a-z].+)
(\([a-z].+\))
```

---

You should look at using a [RegEx visualiser](https://regexr.com/) in future to make it easy for you to tinker with your expressions.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain why the answer has been downvoted?  It is well-structured, answers the question correctly, and provides a succinct explanation along with an example. I'd appreciate the feedback if you think the answer doesn't meet the Stack Overflow standards